# AWS Lambda and Dynamo db: How to filter the result of scan by multiple parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I am new to AWS and dynamo. I working on my project with React.js front-end and AWS (Gateway API, Lambda, Dynamo) backend.
This is my app location:

https://www.alphaux.com

After I click "Get Hint", I receive server response. If I click on a keywords - these keywords will be added to the list of GET params for the request like:
topic=blah&keywords=blah1,blah2,blah3

**Here are the details of my problem:**

In my Lambda:
..
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-west-2'});
exports.handler = async (event) => { ..

from `GET` I am receiving the following params:

```
const topicName = event.queryParams.topic="React";
const keywords = event.queryParams.topic.keywords="blah1,blah2,blah3";
```

..some code here converts keywords string into array:

const keywordsArray = [blah1,blah2,blah3];

In dynamodb they exist in the following way:

```
[ { "S" : "javascript" }, { "S" : "programming" }, { "S" : "React" } ]
```

My Primary partition key is: id (Number)

I have tried different ways and approaches, used scan and query - nothing works. I am stuck..
I have tried the following approach:

```
const listToObjectMappings = () => {
    let x = {};
    /* keywords hardcoded for now: */
    const keywords = ["javascript", "React"]; 
    keywords.map(item => x[':' + item] = item)
    return x
}
let mappings = listToObjectMappings()
let joined = Object.keys(mappings).join();

var params2 = {
        TableName : "my-little-table",
        FilterExpression: 'topic = :topic and #keywords IN (' + joined + ')',
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              '#keywords' : 'keywords'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":topic" : "React"
        }
};
```

```
 var params = {
    TableName: "my-little-table",
    FilterExpression: "#topic = :topic",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#topic": "topic"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":topic": "React"
    }
  };

    let result;
    try {
        /* scan DB */
        result = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        result = ex;
    }
```

When I use "scan", the result is always empty [] if I am trying to use "keywords".
It works only with bare minimum like:

```
    const params = {
        TableName : currentTable,
        FilterExpression:'topic = :topic',
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":topic" : requestedTopic
        }
    };
```

..which gives me all records based on `requestedTopic`.

If I am using "query" it complains that my key name ("id") is too short and has to be at least 3 chars long.

I am stuck and gracefully asking for your help!
Thank you!

Comment: Your filter expression has a typo: "topic = :topic an #keywords IN ..." Presumably "an" should read "and".

Comment: jarmod, thanks for the replay! You are right there is a type, it should be "and". I wish it solves my problem but it does not :-/ Basically I am looking into any solution where I could query (or scan and then filter) my dynamo table by the list of keywords something like [ { "S" : "javascript" }, { "S" : "programming" }, { "S" : "React" } ]..

Comment: So the keywords attribute in your table is itself a list? And you’re trying to match some or all of the query keywords against that? I don’t see how that would work. You use IN to find a single value in a list of values, not to find a list of values in another list of values. If I understand your attempted query correctly.

Comment: Hi jarmod, thanks again for the reply! Yes, the keywords is a list itself. I agree, my query is wrong. I am new to dynamodb. I run out of ideas.. Could you suggest maybe how to structure the query (or scan) the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to match the topic and any one of the keywords then use something like this:

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'mytable',
  FilterExpression: '#tp = :tp AND (contains(#kw, :kw1) OR contains(#kw, :kw2))',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#tp': 'topic',
    '#kw': 'keywords',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':tp': 'React',
    ':kw1': 'react',
    ':kw2': 'react-router',
  },
};
```

If you're trying to match the topic and all of the keywords then use something like this:

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'mytable',
  FilterExpression: '#tp = :tp AND contains(#kw, :kw1) AND contains(#kw, :kw2)',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#tp': 'topic',
    '#kw': 'keywords',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':tp': 'React',
    ':kw1': 'react',
    ':kw2': 'react-router',
  },
};
```

Comment: Hi Jarmod, Thanks!! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In fact I was trying to use it in the format like : ':kw1': {"S": "react"} inside ExpressionAttributeValues. The "':kw1': 'react'" does the magic! I also had to include the following: `IndexName: "topic-index"` and create this index for column "topic". I have also switched from docClient.scan(..) to docClient.query(..) and set the appropriate permissions in IAM for my Lambda to be able to query the table and allow access to the :arn:aws:mydbstuff/index/* Thanks!!